# Magento 2.2.5 Css is not generating

Tags: theme, magento-2.2.5, grunt

I have one project in Magento 2.2.5 and in that the **CSS** is stopped generating
I have run all grunt command and in that it show below error when i run grunt exec

**pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/_reset.less: [L7:C3] Cannot read property 'eval' of null**

Comment: I have facing same issue

Comment: check your pub/static folder and confirm .htaccess is exist.

Comment: I believe this issue comes, if you have customized the css and any variable in the less files is incorrect. I am not 100% sure if that the reason, but you can try to debug from that.

Answer (score 6):

Check the grunt versions into package.json this solves the issue

```
"devDependencies": {
    "glob": "~7.1.1",
    "grunt": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~3.0.4",
    "grunt-banner": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-continue": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-eslint": "~19.0.0",
    "grunt-exec": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-jscs": "~3.0.1",
    "grunt-replace": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-styledocco": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "~0.2.3",
    "grunt-text-replace": "~0.4.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "~5.2.1",
    "load-grunt-config": "~0.19.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-minify": "~2.0.3",
    "path": "~0.12.7",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
    "squirejs": "~0.2.1",
    "strip-json-comments": "~2.0.1",
    "time-grunt": "~1.0.0",
    "underscore": "~1.7.0"
}
```

add this into your package.json by checking the other dependencies
make sure there is no duplicate entry

Have look into my package.json file the change i had done, so you might get idea about the changes.

[image]

> Into terminal and to your project folder run command npm install to install the dependencies then use grunt command

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');

Comment: its already exist in core_config_data